# How can I write arabic text in image in PHP

Tags: php, image, text, arabic

I tried to write an Arabic text in an image with PHP.
This is my code:

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: image/png; charset=utf8");
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(150, 30);

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 100, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

$font = 'tahoma.ttf';
$t = strrev('إن الدين عند الله الإسلام');
$text=utf8_encode($t);
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: you can use this link
[look here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284896/export-arabic-text-as-images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What’s the output?

The strrev function is not unicode compatible
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php
See the comments there for examples of unicode compatible ones.

Also see the imagettftext page,
I think the following comment is exactly what you need:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php#97767

Comment: With your original code? Did you try / read the links I posted?

Comment: **Sorry, but this wont work**. The link to the comment treats Arabic chars as an array. Which assumes only one form of the char is valid, which is not. Arabic chars change shape based on position in the word, a glyph. For a similar question and an answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993265/writing-text-with-diacritic-nikud-vocalization-marks-using-pil-python-imag/25727238#25727238](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993265/writing-text-with-diacritic-nikud-vocalization-marks-using-pil-python-imag/25727238#25727238)

Comment: for PHP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780339/write-arabic-to-image-error/25753686#25753686

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

1. include("fagd.php");
2. use imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, fagd($text));

fagd.php codes are here:

http://cdn.shirazitco.ir/fagd.txt

Comment: amazing solution.. worked perfect for me !! but the link is broken so i added another link: http://www.koders.com/php/fidBBD43C6EF0FFB00FED0AC734BC2EFB293A6CBBC3.aspx

Comment: hmmm i tried this but it didn't work... could you post how you did it? I still got garbled (not Arabic) characters.